# Display folder in webpart on page

Tags: document

I need to display folder in a web part on a page in SharePoint 2010. I was trying to do it using content query web part but it gives only items not the folder but i need to show folder in the web part is there any alternative way for this.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a page view web part to display the page with the folder in the document library and then use some css on that page to hide navigation etc.